# how to check if given c++ string or char* contains only digits?

Tags: c++, string, pattern-matching

Or from the other way around find first non digit character.

Do the same functions apply for string and for char* ?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Of course, there are many ways to test a string for only numeric characters. Two possible methods are:

```
bool is_digits(const std::string &str)
{
    return str.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos;
}
```

or

```
bool is_digits(const std::string &str)
{
    return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isdigit); // C++11
}
```

Comment: Why here is double colon in isdigit ? It does not compile without it, `std::isdigit` doesn't work either.

Comment: @Dfr: There are more than one `isdigit` functions (from `<cctype>` and `<locale>` headers). [See this related answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13262555/445976)

Comment: The c++11 way honestly rocks :)

Comment: This method does not work if the wanted type is a floating number such as scientific format, sscanf is a better option.

Comment: @Jichao: You're correct but that would be a different question.

Comment: @Blastfurnace : just out of curiosity I want to know why have you used pass by reference in the function above?

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay: I used references to avoid copying the passed `std::string`  parameters (copying would be potentially expensive). They are also `const` to ensure I don't modify the caller's variables. Using const references this way is very common in C++ programming.

Comment: This is one old answer. But one should be aware that both of these return `true` for empty strings. As one is already looking for `0`, it would make sense to add `str.size() > 0` to the comparison.

Comment: @Oliver but the question is about containing only digits or finding the first non-digit - and empty string does not contain any character that is not allowed.
For checking that the string is not empty using `!str.empty()`  is a bit more clear.

Answer (score 17):

Several people already mentioned to use `isdigit()`. However, note that this isn't entirely trivial because `char` can be signed which would cause a negative value to be passed to `isdigit()`. However, this function can only take positive values. That is, you want something akin to this:

```
if (s.end() == std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(),
    [](unsigned char c)->bool { return !isdigit(c); })) {
    std::cout << "string '" << s << "' contains only digits\n";
}
```

It seems the reasoning for the conversion to `unsigned char` isn't obvious. So, here are the relevant quotes from their respective standards:

According to ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (or ISO/IEC 9899:1999) 7.4 paragraph 1 the following applies to the arguments of the functions from `<ctype.h>`:

> ... In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be
>   representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the
>   argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

Unfortunately, the C++ standard doesn't specify that `char` is an unsigned type. Instead it specifies in ISO/IEC 14882:2011 3.9.1 [basic.fundamental] paragraph 1:

> ... It is implementation-defined whether a `char` object can hold negative values. ...

Clearly, a negative value cannot be represented as an `unsigned char`. That is, if `char` is using a signed type on an implementation (there are actually several which do, e.g., it is signed on MacOS using gcc or clang) there is the danger that calling any of the `<ctype.h>` function would cause undefined behavior.

Now, why does the conversion to `unsigned char` does the right things?

According to 4.7 [conv.integral] paragraph 2:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). —end note ]

That is, the conversion from a [potentially] signed `char` to `unsigned char` is well-defined and causes the result to be in the permitted range for the `<ctype.h>` functions.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you: Do you say that converting `char` to `unsigned char`, potentially producing overflows or UB, is a better idea than on relying on `isdigit()` checking for `c` being of `['0'..'9']`, which is specifically taking `int` as input? Any citations or justifications might be helpful, if possible.

Comment: The conversion from `char` to `unsigned char` will not overflow or anything. It will retain the original bits but yield a value in the defined range of `isdigit()` even if `char` is signed and the character is in the negative range. The relevant quote is in C's 7.4 paragraph 1.

Answer (score 6):

`isdigit(int)` tells you if a character is a digit. If you are going to assume ASCII and base 10, you can also use:

```
int first_non_digit_offset= strspn(string, "0123456789")
```

Answer (score 6):

In the same spirit as Misha's answer, but more correct: `sscanf(buf, "%*u%*c")==1`.

`scanf` returns 0 if the `%d` digit extraction fails, and 2 if there is anything after the digits captured by `%c`. And since `*` prevents the value from being stored, you can't even get an overflow.

Comment: This is the best answer so far. It works with signed/unsigned, floating vs integer etc.

Answer (score 5):

The `cctype` header file has a good number of character classifications functions which you can use on each character in the string. For numeric checks, that would be `isdigit`.

The following program shows how to check each character of a C or C++ string ( the process is pretty much identical in terms of checking the actual characters, the only real difference being how to get the length):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
int main (void) {
    const char *xyzzy = "42x";
    std::cout << xyzzy << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < std::strlen (xyzzy); i++) {
        if (! std::isdigit (xyzzy[i])) {
            std::cout << xyzzy[i] << " is not numeric.\n";
        }
    }

    std::string plugh ("3141y59");
    std::cout << plugh << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < plugh.length(); i++) {
        if (! std::isdigit (plugh[i])) {
            std::cout << plugh[i] << " is not numeric.\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`#include <regex>`

```
std::string string( "I only have 3 dollars!" );
std::cout << std::regex_search( string, std::regex( "\\d+" ) ); // true
```

and

```
std::string string( "I only have three dollars!" );
std::cout << std::regex_search( string, std::regex( "\\d+" ) ); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/isdigit/) you can use isdigit function as follow:

```
// isdigit example (C++)
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <string>         // std::string
#include <locale>         // std::locale, std::isdigit
#include <sstream>        // std::stringstream

int main ()
{
  std::locale loc;
  std::string str="1776ad";
  if (isdigit(str[0],loc))
  {
    int year;
    std::stringstream(str) >> year;
    std::cout << "The year that followed " << year << " was " << (year+1) << ".\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note: there is 2 types of isdigit the other version is local independent and ASCII based.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a strict requirement that you can find exactly where the first non-character digit is, then you'll have to check each character. If not, I'd use either something like this:

```
unsigned safe_atoi(const std::string& a)
{
    std::stringstream s(a);
    unsigned b;
    s >> b;
    return b;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677158/how-to-detect-negative-numbers-as-parsing-errors-when-reading-unsigned-integers