# Finding an alphanumeric character in a string using find_if and isalnum

Tags: c++, string, stl, g++

I'm using **g++ 4.7**.

What I'm trying to do is this,

```
find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), isalnum);
```

where `isalnum` is defined in `cctype` and `s` is a string.

```
logman.cpp:68:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘find_if(std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator, std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

However, this works,

```
bool my_isalnum(int c) {
    return isalnum(c);
}

find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), my_isalnum);
```

How can I get this to work without creating my own function?

Comment: If C++11 is ok for you, you could use a lambda expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler is having trouble disambiguating between [this function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum) and [this function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalnum).  You want the first one, and you'll have to help the compiler out here, by specifying the signature with a cast:

```
find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), (int(*)(int))isalnum);
```

Comment: Note that adding the scope resolution operator `::isalnum` also works.

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
auto result = std::find_if (begin(s), end(s), std::isalnum);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#include <algorithm >
#include <cctype>

auto result = std::find_if(std::begin(s), std::end(s),  isalnum) ;
```