# std::isgraph is ambiguous when `using namespace std` is used

Tags: c++

I tried to use `std::isgraph` from `<cctype>` as a predicate in `find_if`. But compiler errored out saying:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘find_if(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator< const char*, std::basic_string< char> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator< const char*, std::basic_string< char> >, < **unresolved overloaded** function type>)’

I have used `using namespace std;` and from my understanding there will be two `isgraph` functions visible in the global namespace. So `::isgraph` or simply `isgraph` should be ambiguous and `std::isgraph` should not be ambiguous. On the contrary, using `::isgraph` is OK while `std::isgraph` is not.

Can someone explain what I missed? A few related questions are [What are the function requirements to use as the predicate in the find_if from the <algorithm> library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971249/what-are-the-function-requirements-to-use-as-the-predicate-in-the-find-if-from-t) and [C++ using standard algorithms with strings, count_if with isdigit, function cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039858/c-using-standard-algorithms-with-strings-count-if-with-isdigit-function-cast). But they didn't answer why explicitly specifying `std::` still doesn't resolve to the function in the `std` namespace.

**EDIT**:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
   string root_line = "hello";
   auto ind = distance(root_line.begin(), find_if(root_line.begin(), root_line.end(), std::isgraph));

   cout << ind;

   return 0;
}
```

I compiled the above code with g++ -std=c++11 of version 4.8.4

Comment: Could you give a few line example I can compile and play around with?

Comment: It works for me, so that's weird.

Comment: @Rich This totally works in VS2015 but nowhere else, it seems.

Comment: If you remove the using and put `std::` in front of the stuff, the error persists, so that is a red herring.

Comment: @NeilKirk Oh wow, Thanks! cppreference's own search didn't show the one in the <locale> header. That solved this mystery.

Comment: @Rich, However, it is listed in the "See also" part of the other `std::isgraph` page.

Comment: @chris oops.... i should start looking at those sections now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::isgraph` is overloaded.

To resolve the ambiguity you *could* cast it to the relevant function pointer type.

But in order to use it correctly the argument should be converted to `unsigned char`, so better define a wrapper function:

```
using Byte = unsigned char;

auto is_graphical( char const ch )
    -> bool
{ return !!isgraph( Byte( ch ) ); }
```

Note that this only works with single-byte encodings, and that it depends on the current locale at the C level (see `setlocale`).

Comment: `std::isgraph` is overloaded? what is the other signature it has? how come I couldn't find it on cppreference?

Comment: @Rich: I think I maybe erred here. The error message says it's overloaded with the OPs C++ implementation. ANd there is a `std::graph` function template. But I can so far not find information that it can be specialized for `char` and `wchar_t`. Checking... And thanks!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isgraph
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isgraph

Comment: OK, it turns out the answer text is technically correct. A function template of the same name is sufficient to prevent successful overload resolution. I was doubting myself here, thinking that the concrete function should win over the template, but I was wrong thinking that I was wrong. Uh.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `std::isgraph` defined in `<cctype>` and a different `std::isgraph` defiend in <locale>. Using overloaded functions as functors can be a pain as the compiler has difficulty figuring out which version of the function you want. You can resolve the ambiguity by casting, or using a lambda or named wrapper function as suggested by @Cheersandhth.-Alf

```
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   
   std::string root_line = "hello";
   auto ind = std::distance(root_line.begin(), std::find_if(root_line.begin(), root_line.end(), static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::isgraph)));
   std::cout << ind;
}
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/heSSEZ

Comment: Neil, are you the Neil from years ago?

Comment: is the header <locale> somehow included in by other headers? Is there any way to find out which headers include a certain other header file (other than looking at the source code if possible)?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Possibly, I've been Neil for quite some time. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @NeilKirk: Sorry, I think I confused you with Neil Butterworth. He was one of the high profile ["I'm leaving Stack Overflow" users](http://kera.name/articles/2012/03/why-i-broke-up-with-stack-overflow/). 'Races in Orbit, the author of the linked to I'm-also-leaving-article, is back. I thought you might be the Butterworth Neil coming back. In a way, that's compliment. IIRC, long after NB left one could recognize his answers as highly upvoted no-username answers.