# Why does "std::isdigit" report "no matching overloaded function" in C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, namespaces, std

I implemented the accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c) which uses `std::isdigit`:

```
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}
```

It works fine on Mac OS X. However when using MSVC in VS17 Professional 15.9.3 for Windows 10, I get this compiler error:

```
C2672 'std::isdigit': no matching overloaded function found.
```

I am porting code and KNOW this works on Mac OS X and clang. I have included `<string>`, `<cctype>`, `<ctype.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` nothing helps.

It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Please provide [mre]. It states that no matching **overloaded** function found. This has nothing to do with Windows, since I can use `std::digit` just fine with vc++: https://rextester.com/YMZII3430

Comment: How about you include the actual *code* ? Further, you didn't link an *answer* ; you linked a question, which has a multitude of answers, and I'd rather not waste time guessing which answer you're talking about. Include the code, ideally in a [mcve] in *this* question.

Comment: Should I include the code from the answer I linked to or is it enough to link to it? I'm new to this, let me know thx.

Comment: @pifthemighty 1) "_Should I include the code from the answer I linked to or is it enough to link to it?_" You should include [mre], of the code **you** are compiling. 2) "_I'm new to this_" Did you take the [tour], and read through [ask], and [help], before asking?

Comment: Your question should be self-contained. Any links are for *assistance*, not *dependence*. A *full* [mcve] along with verbatim error messages and line numbers comment-marked (but *not* included in source) is ideal.

Comment: You say you have included `<cctype>`, `<ctype.h>`, and `<stdlib.h>`. You also need to include `<string>`.     With some implementations `<string>` is included by other headers but that is NOT required.

Comment: Try including both `<string>` and `<cctype>`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added the includes, my bad for not having a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

The function `isdigit()` is define in the C header `ctype.h` or the C++ header `cctype`.

If you include `ctype.h` from your C++ file then `isdigit()` is defined in the global namespace (and some implementations also place in in std::).

Conversely if you include `cctype` from your C++ file then `isdigit()` is defined in the standard namespace `std::` (and some implementations also place in the global namespace).

In your case you have `#included <ctype.h>` and on windows it looks like that means it is only available in the global namespace. Thus `std::isdigit()` does not match any known functions. Try changing your include to `#include <cctype>`.

```
#include <cctype>
bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}
```

Comment: I like this answer. I tried this and I've had no luck. I've switched between `#include <ctype.h>` and `#include <cctype>` and then both and neither, none of it seems to help. The only thing that works is changing the line `while (it != s.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;` to `while (it != s.end() && isdigit(*it)) ++it;`. I'm not entirely sure why but I think this answer seems to shed some light on what might be going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @pifthemighty Then you have a non conformant tools. What compiler (and version of compiler) are you using. Might also be useful to known what version of Windows you are using.

Answer (score -2):

As it turns out, it is a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908037/stdisgraph-is-ambiguous-when-using-namespace-std-is-used/33908112). There is some ambiguity when you use the std namespace, i.e., `using namespace std;`. If you change `std::isdigit` in the code to `isdigit` it will compile on Windows.

```
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end() && isdigit(*it)) ++it;
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}
```

Comment: "_There is some ambiguity when you use the std namespace_" There are good reasons, why one [shouldn't be `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) at all.

Comment: The linked question only occurs when taking the address of the function, but your posted code does not do that