# how to do type checking of command line input in c++

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I have a simple code wherein i am finding simple interest and compound interest. The issue I am facing is that I have to use CLI for input.
I need one int and two floats to work with. Earlier i was using cin.fail() which was doing the type checking for me and that worked perfectly but i need to take CLI such that inputs such as 1000 1? 5 are treated as invalid. Please help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    int p;
    float r,t,ci;

    p=atoi(argv[1]);
    r=atof(argv[2]);
    t=atof(argv[3]);

    if(p<=0 || r==0 || t<=0) {
        //we want p>0 t>0 and r==0 from the logic that atof will retrun 0 if r is non numeric
        cout<<"Invalid Input"<<endl;
    }
    else {
        float si=(p*r*t)/100;
        cout<<"Simple interest:"<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<si<<endl;
        ci=p*pow((1+r/100),t)-p;
        cout<<"Compound interest:"<<ci<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is preventing you from checking those conditions with a simple good old `if` condition?

Comment: i am not able to pinpoint the condition i should use!

Comment: @user3918038 You should reformulate the question, and possibly the title to make it clear what you are asking. Do you want a validation function for string-formatted floating point numbers?

Comment: yes, this has nothing to do with real life application. I have to submit it for the class portal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check if given c++ string or char\* contains only digits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888748/how-to-check-if-given-c-string-or-char-contains-only-digits)

Comment: I don't understand how an opinionated comment that has nothing to do with the OP gets the most upvotes...

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: Your suggested 'duplicate' is wrong, as the input here may contain a decimal point.

Comment: @barakmanos And a minus sign too :) Oh my, such a difficult extension... The first solution literally lists the valid chars.

Comment: `argv` is character array, so at first you need to determine where it ends.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this function to your code:

```
#include <ctype.h>

static bool isnumeric(char* theArgument, int maxdec)
{
    int decimalpoint = 0;
    while(*theArgument)
    {
        if (!isdigit(*theArgument))
        {
            if ('.' == *theArgument && maxdec <= ++decimalpoint)
            {
                continue;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Call it for each of your arguments, with the maximum number of decimal points the argument can allow. In your case, that would be `isnumeric(argv[1],0)`, `isnumeric(argv[2],1)`, `isnumeric(argv[3],1)`. That will tell you if your numbers are in fact formatted as nonnegative decimal numbers. A little more logic (not shown here) will also tell you if they have a minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtol` and `strtod` instead of `atoi` and `atof`:

```
long int p;
double r,t;

char* endptr1;
char* endptr2;
char* endptr3;

p = strtol(argv[1], &endptr1, 10);
r = strtod(argv[2], &endptr2);
t = strtod(argv[3], &endptr3);

if (*endptr1 != 0 || *endptr2 != 0 || *endptr3 != 0)
{
    cout<<"Invalid Input"<<endl;
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is character array, so it contains more characters.

Solution should be:

1. Explode your argv into 3 parts, separator should be space (or multiple) symbol.
2. Now cast it using `strtol` and `strtod`.
3. Validate. `strtol` and `strtod` returns zero if no success, so in case you got zero, check if input was actualy `'0'`.