# Verify user input is 5 digit number

Tags: c++

I am working on a project where the user is prompted to enter a zip code. I need to verify it is a five digit number (I don't need to verify it is an actual zip code).

Here is a portion of my code.

```
string userInput;
cout << "Zip Code> ";
getline(cin, userInput, '\n');


while (stoi(userInput)<10000 || stoi(userInput) > 99999){
    cout << endl << endl << "You must enter a valid zip code. Please try again." << endl;
    cout << "Zip Code>" << endl;
    getline(cin, userInput, '\n');
}

PropertyRec.setZipCode(stoi(userInput));
```

This works fine unless the zip code starts with a zero.  If it does, the validation is no good and the initial zero never saves to the variable once the input string is converted to an integer.

Should I leave the zip code as a string when saving to the database?  If so, how can I verify there are exactly 5 characters and each character is numeric?

Comment: take it as a string and check its size()?

Comment: Just check that there are five characters in the input and that each character is a digit.

Comment: Also, don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: the above comments are better than doing this, but for future reference, you could `int code = stoi(userInput)` and then use `code` rather than recomputing `stoi(userInput)`. If you can do something once and cache the result, you usually come out ahead.

Comment: if you can't add them then store it as string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [std::all_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of), [isdigit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and `string::size()` to determine if the zip code is valid:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
//...
bool isValidZipCode(const std::string& s)
{
   return s.size() == 5 && std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), ::isdigit);
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/yyMUss)

[**Declarative Programming**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) plug:

Note that if you say out loud the line in the `isValidZipCode` function, it fits your description (the string must have a size equal to 5 and "all of" the characters must be a digit).

Comment: Thanks guys!  Works great.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are receiving input as a `std::string`, you can use [`std::string::length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) (or `std::string::size`) to ensure you have the right amount of characters:

```
if (userInput.length() != 5)
{
    // Input is invalid
}
```

To ensure they're only numbers, as @user4581301 points out you can use [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) and [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) (or check out answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888748/how-to-check-if-given-c-string-or-char-contains-only-digits))

```
if (userInput.length() == 5 && std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), ::isdigit))
{
    // Input is valid
}
```

It's also worth noting that the following line

```
PropertyRec.setZipCode(stoi(userInput));
```

Will remove any leading `0` you have, so you may need to store your zip code as a `std::string` (unless you implement handling that will assume any zip code that's < 5 has leading 0's, but it's likely far easier to store it exactly as-is)

Answer (score 0):

You can use string size function for getting the size of the string. Save the string size in other variable and validate it whether it less than five or not.