# How to convert string to int in c++?

Tags: c++, string, int, codeblocks

I am creating a phone registration program to check if a phone number entered is valid. I have tried searching google numerous times and have figured out how to check the phone numbers length and whether it starts with "04"; it seem as though there is nothing to check whether a string can be converted to an unsigned integer without an error though. My current code is:

```
bool Is_Valid(string phone) {
if (phone.length() == 10 && phone.substr(0,2) == "04") {
    return 1;
} else {
return 0;
}
}
```

The desired result would be that if the user entered in a string that is ten characters long and starts with "04" but the string has a letter in it, the function would return false. Likewise if the character entered in a string that was ten characters long and it started with "04" as well as having no letters, it would return true. Thank You.

Comment: I have a c++ for dummies book, is that good or bad?

Comment: What about strtol?  If endptr doesn't point to the end of the string afterwards then not the whole string was a number.  You also need to check that the integer returned is not negative because that means there was a minus sign at the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find difficulties if you convert such strings to ints because those have a leading zero, which will be dropped on conversion.

I'd suggest `std::all_of` and `::isdigit` from the standard library;

```
if (phone.length() == 10 && phone.substr(0, 2) == "04"
    && std::all_of(phone.begin(), phone.end(), ::isdigit)) // added
```

This would work. Remember to include `<algorithm>` and `<cctype>`.

Please note that it requires C++11 (or newer), which is activated by `-std=c++11` if you are using gcc.
If C++11 is unavailable, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8889045/5118228  explains how to roll your own tester function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::ostringstream`, such as:

```
std::string example = "10";
unsigned int value;
std::istringstream text_stream(example);
text_stream >> value;
```

You may want to use the `dec` modifier to handle any preceding zeros:
`text_stream >> dec >> value;`

<s>I haven't tried it though.  The issue is based on C++ numeric constants that begin with 0 are treated as octal (base 8).</s>

**Edit 1: Example program**

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::string example = "010";
    unsigned int value;
    std::istringstream text_stream(example);
    text_stream >> value;
    if (value == 10)
    {
        std::cout << "Coversion correct\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid conversion.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: error: variable 'std::ostringstream text_stream' has initializer but incomplete type

Comment: error: request for member 'length' in 'Phone', which is of non-class type unsigned int

Comment: Sorry, my bad, wrong string stream.  Use `std::istringstream`.  See my latest edit.