# Checking if a string is a valid number (no letters at all)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So I wrote a function that checks whether or not a string has a numeric character. Even if there is just 1 letter in a group of numbers, it should return false. However it doesn't. I'm not sure if loops work differently in C++ or not.

```
bool isStringAValidNumber(string str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (!isdigit(str[i])) {
            return false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of isdigit?

Comment: @LajosArpad Isn't `isdigit` defined under `std::`? It basically checks if a char is within `[0-9]`.

Comment: You are going to get a reference from str[i]. Try to cast to int and check if it works.  Dont need the break after false

Comment: @Srikan "*Try to cast to int and check if it works*" - excuse me? Casting `char` to `int` will always work

Comment: It should be either `!isdigit( (unsigned char)str[i] )` or `!std::isdigit(str[i], std::locale())`  The `is` function family are quirky due to history of being imported from the C language. Also this will not work for UTF-8 strings obviously. If you are still having trouble please post  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows unexpected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check if given c++ string or char\* contains only digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888748/how-to-check-if-given-c-string-or-char-contains-only-digits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int isStringAValidNumber(string str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (!isdigit(str[i])) {
            return 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}


int main()
{
    cout << isStringAValidNumber("1sd2345");
    cout << endl;
    cout << isStringAValidNumber("1s2345");
    cout << endl;
    cout << isStringAValidNumber("12345");
}
```

works just fine...

the return is:

```
0
0
1
```

[Compile Online](http://cpp.sh/22wb)