# C++ limit input to only be integars so letters aren't valid

Tags: c++

See code below.  It works fine for numbers but if I enter a letter (eg 'a'), it will output 'first number 0 is divisible by second number, 6487956' without asking for input of second number.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int first, second;

    cout << "Please enter your first number (must be an integer) : "  ;
    cin >> first  ;
    cout << "Please enter your second number (must be an integer) : ";
    cin >> second ;

    if (first % second == 0)
        cout << "The first number, " << first << ", is divisible by the second number, "     << second << ".";
        else
        cout << "The first number, " << first << ", is not divisible by the second number, " << second << ".";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot limit C++ input to integers. All you can do is read a string, and check if the string is an integer and convert it if it is.

Comment: Check `cin` state after reading.  It will fail if the user did not input any numbers.

Comment: @Quimby That is true, but it will not fail if the user entered a number followed by some non-number, `123abc` for instance. I don't think that input counts as an integer, but it would read as one.

Comment: @john You are right but that is the behaviour of cin. If the author needs the full line to be a number, use `getline`.

Comment: @Quimby Yes, which is what my comment was essentially saying. Unfortunately the partial solution of checking the `cin` state gets mentioned too often, and I imagine many newbies implement it without realising it doesn't really do what they wanted.

Comment: @john Fair enough.

Comment: I use:  `int get_int(istream& in) { string line; if (!getline(in, line)) throw runtime_error("istream"); stringstream ss{line}; int result; if (!(ss >> result)) throw runtime_error("bad input"); return result; }` then I can use `int first = get_int(cin);`

Comment: @Eljay would that go after 'int main' and would I need to include any '{' anywhere?  Would you possibly be able to put your comment as an answer so I can see how to lay it out?  Many thanks :)

Comment: I can't add it as an answer, because the question is closed.  That would be a freestanding function, which could appear before main.  The `int first = get_int(cin);` would be in the body of main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example which will not accept if input has any characters. [Function to check if string has only numbers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888748/how-to-check-if-given-c-string-or-char-contains-only-digits)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool is_digits(const std::string& str)
{
    return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), std::isdigit);
}

void get_number(std::string& number, const char* string) {
    std::cout << string;
    std::getline(std::cin, number);
    if (!is_digits(number)) {
        get_number(number, string);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string first, second;
    get_number(first, "Please enter your first number (must be an integer) : ");
    get_number(second, "Please enter your second number (must be an integer) : ");

    if (std::stoi(first) % std::stoi(second) == 0)
        std::cout << "The first number, " << first << ", is divisible by the second number, " << second << ".";
    else
        std::cout << "The first number, " << first << ", is not divisible by the second number, " << second << ".";
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool is_digits(const std::string& str)
{
    return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), std::isdigit);
}

int get_number(const char* string) {
    static std::string number;
    std::cout << string;
    std::getline(std::cin, number);
    if (!is_digits(number)) {
        get_number(string);
    }
    return std::stoi(number);
}

int main()
{
    int first = get_number("Please enter your first number (must be an integer) : ");
    int second = get_number("Please enter your second number (must be an integer) : ");

    if (first % second == 0)
        std::cout << "The first number, " << first << ", is divisible by the second number, " << second << ".";
    else
        std::cout << "The first number, " << first << ", is not divisible by the second number, " << second << ".";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where in my code would I include that line (before or after what line)?  Thanks

Comment: @LWeaver Just look at the 2nd duplicate links answers. There's explained in detail what you'll need to do.

Comment: @pesuww I entered `123abc` and your code didn't detect the error.

Comment: So you want it to detect error if any char is given? I made it so that it will just take the integers. Do you want version which gives error from chars?

Comment: I added a new version.