# std::istream to unsigned numerical value, how to detect negative values?

Tags: c++, stream

I'm working on a template function to convert a string to a number for some legacy code to be compiled without C++11.

The function is:

```
template<typename T>
void checkValid( const std::string& val )
{
    std::stringstream str1;
    T temp1;

    str1 << val;
    str1 >> temp1;
    if ( str1.fail() || str1.bad() )
        std::cout << "error, " << val << " is not a valid string value" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "ok, " << val << " is converted to " << temp1 << std::endl;
}
```

It works pretty well, except for negative values:

```
// valid integer
checkValid<int>( "3" );
// valid integer
checkValid<int>( "-1000" );
// invalid integer
checkValid<int>( "foo" );
// invalid integer out of range (>INT_MAX)
checkValid<int>( "8393930300303" );
// invalid integer out of range (<INT_MIN)
checkValid<int>( "-8393930300303" );

// valid unsigned integer
checkValid<unsigned int>( "3" );
// invalid unsigned integer
checkValid<unsigned int>( "foo" );
// unsigned integer out of range (>UINT_MAX)
checkValid<unsigned int>( "8393930300303" );
// unsigned integer out of range (<0)
checkValid<unsigned int>( "-3" );
```

This outputs:

```
ok, 3 is converted to 3
ok, -1000 is converted to -1000
error, foo is not a valid string value
error, 8393930300303 is not a valid string value
error, -8393930300303 is not a valid string value
ok, 3 is converted to 3
error, foo is not a valid string value
error, 8393930300303 is not a valid string value
ok, -3 is converted to 4294967293
```

While I would expect, for the last line:

```
error, -3 is not a valid string value
```

Negative string values are not handled correctly when target type is unsigned. What would be the best strategy to fix `checkValid` and have it behave as expected for all types (signed, unsigned numericals but also float/double)?

Comment: "not handled correctly when target type is unsigned" - unsigned types can*not* hold negative values. That's what unsigned *means*.

Comment: Add a (partial) specialization for `unsigned` types, and check if the first non-space character of the argument is a dash (`'-'`)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl OP expects the stream to fail, not that the `unsigned int` properly represents `-3`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I know that. That's what I would expect "-3" to produce an error...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: That could even be generic to all types (if std::numeric_limits<T>::min() == 0, then string should not start with '-' )....but is there no smarter way to do that?

Comment: Do you just want to know why this is or how to fix it?  For the why see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677158/how-to-detect-negative-numbers-as-parsing-errors-when-reading-unsigned-integers)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Can't partially specialize functions.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Actually both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams are allowed to take in negative numbers for unsigned types.  It has the same mechanics as

```
unsigned type foo = -some_value
```

Since they can take in a negative number the stream will never fail and you will have the normal behavior of assigning a negative number to an unsigned type.

We can add a check for this though in your function.  For a type `T`, `T() - T(1) < 0`, will only be true if the type is signed, otherwise the subtraction would wrap around and become the largest value `T` can represent.  So, if we check that condition, and the string starts with a `'-'`, then you know it is not a "valid" value.  That makes you function look like

```
template<typename T>
void checkValid( const std::string& val )
{
    std::stringstream str1;
    T temp1;

    str1 << val;
    str1 >> temp1;
    if ( str1.fail() || str1.bad() || (!(T() - T(1) < T()) && val[0] == '-')  )
        std::cout << "error, " << val << " is not a valid string value" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "ok, " << val << " is converted to " << temp1 << std::endl;
}
```

If your string can have leading whitespace then you will want to replace the `val[0] == '-'` check with something like `val[val.find_first_not_of(" ")] == '-'`

Comment: [`std::is_unsigned`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned) can be used.

Comment: @xskxzr The OP doesn't have C++11